# XPages viewPanel expanding one twisty taking long time

Tags: xpages

I have 1 level categorized view with around 80000 + documents and still increasing. 
Initial loading of view with collapse all categories, Expand All/Collapse All pager control, works very fast, in a second. 
But When I am trying to individual category, just one by one, takes around 10 seconds delay. Its a huge slow performance for users.

Please help on this, any fix available for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 9.0.1 you can enable a new property that increases performance of categorized views.

See http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=performant-view-navigation-for-notes-domino-9.0.1

Comment: We are using server 8.5.3. Do we have any such configuration for this version?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to revisit your UI pattern. Categories and pagers don't match well. See http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-7UDMQS and fix as Per suggested the parameters